# How to set the startup order of pods of a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I have a kubernetes cluster that is setup using kops on AWS.

I don't need this cluster during weekends.

So I close it by setting its auto-scaling group's minimum and maximum capacity to 0 on Friday.

The problem with this method is that the startup order of the pods is not fixed.

I mean when I opens the cluster on Monday, sometimes pod A starts before pod B, sometimes pod B starts before pod A.

Is it possible to set the startup order of the pods in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. You can use [pod priority](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/#effect-of-pod-priority-on-scheduling-order) to influence the scheduling order of Pods. But most likely both Pod A and Pod B will schedule closely after each other given capacity. Then factors like image download time and image startup time will determine when a Pod actually starts.

If you need e.g a database to be available before its clients, you can use [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to make the main container wait on a certain condition before starting.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I finally use `initContainers` to set the startup order.